# how to avoid field disposed in a WizardPage

Tags: eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have a Wizard , with two wizard Pages.
On each page I have controls, on page 2 I have some text fields, 
in my controller I wanto to access them, like this:

```
f2.setCantSurcos(Integer.getInteger(wizard.getTxtCantsurcos()));
```

Where wizard method is a wrapper to page 2:
    public String getTxtCantsurcos() {
        return this.page2.getTxtCantsurcos();
    }

The problem is that the method throw me this error:
"   Widget is disposed"

I suppose this is because I'm tryin to access the widget directly:

```
public String getTxtCantsurcos() {
    return txtCantsurcos.getText();
}
```

If i'm correct, I should move/copy the content of the Text field to a String attribute.
But, how to do that when the user click on Next Button ?

Best regards.
Nico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try and wait for the next button to be clicked.

Use `addModifyListener` to add a modify listener to each text control and save the value in a string whenever the text is modified.

You can also use JFace 'data binding' for this sort of thing.

Comment: thanks @greg-449, I'll try that, what I do is Override PerformFinish method and save values of the controls to Wizardpages properties.

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot comment Greg's post, I post an answer:
Here is a snippet of a simple data binding example:

http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/plain/examples/org.eclipse.jface.examples.databinding/src/org/eclipse/jface/examples/databinding/snippets/Snippet014WizardDialog.java